# Only on iOS 10.3.2. Error: The operation could not be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)

Tags: youtube, uiwebview, ios10.3.2

iOS Version on which the bug is reproducable: **10.3.2**

Code runs correctly on iOS 10.3.1 and earlier

Whenever I try to load a youtube video url on UIWebView, I got the following error:

```
The operation could not be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)
```

The `UIWebView` request loading is simple and done like below:

```
// ...
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
self.webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
// URL is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hntVmN2aK8k

func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error) {
   print(error.localizedDescription) // The operation could not be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)
}
```